# Node Sass Undefined variable

Tags: vue.js, node-sass

I'm trying to setup an existing vuejs project on AWS

```
  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

background: $info;
           ^
  Undefined variable: "$info".
  in /var/www/html/tradeline-creditpartner/src/assets/scss/core/scafholding.scss (line 226, c                                                             olumn 17)

  @ ./src/assets/scss/app.scss 4:14-229 14:3-18:5 15:22-237
  @ ./src/main.js
   @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://IP:8081/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-serv                                                             er.js ./src/main.js
```

However when trying to serve the project
`npm run serve` It keeps showing the above error

Is there something wrong with vuejs installation?

that's the only error I keep encountering.

Comment: Need more information: where is the variable defined? Is it defined at all? If it’s defined within a different file, are you importing that file?

Comment: Did you find the solution?